# How to add com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.InputCoercionException as a dependency in gradle?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, jackson

I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategies which is used in another project. I have included jackson jar in current gradle project as well. But while starting the project I am getting the above mentioned error. Seems like we need to add com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.InputCoercionException as an dependency but I am not able to understand where to add this as a dependency ? Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` Either means - missing dependency with class `com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategies` or class was removed meaning jackson libs versions used in your project dependencies won't work together.

How to start solving problems like those.

1, Via IDE try to find missing class if is present. If is not present then try to find jar with missing class on internet and add as dependency. In case your IDE show class is present then problem may be with import scope. Scope management differ per used technology so provide detail which one you use or paste dependencies from build.kts . Make sure you use `implementation` in case you import this class in project and not `runtimeOnly`.

2, You found class then try to print project dependency tree command differ per used technology. For gradle `./gradlew dependencies` or for submodule `./gradlew submoduleName:dependencies` and look at versions of jackson in your project.

3, Check jackson lib with version listed via dependency tree contains missing class.

How to avoid problem like those with spring boot.

I would recoment to use BOM provided by spring boot project, versions in there should work together.

For gradle with kotlin DSL we import it like this

```
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin


plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.2"
}

dependencies {
    val springBootPlatform = platform(SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES)
    annotationProcessor(springBootPlatform)

    implementation(springBootPlatform)
    //this version has to be searched for spring boot version
    implementation(platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.0"))
    
    //put desired jackson dependencies
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

}
```

Comment: Thanks !! The issue was the conflicting jars that were getting included from different  jars !! Resolved using the dependency tree and added all the three jackson jars with the updates and same version !!

Comment: Good. I would recommend to use version management via `val springBootPlatform = platform(SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES)` in case of Spring Boot. It will bring versions, which work togerher. Then using it with ` implementation(springBootPlatform)`. On our project we had problems with libs versions until this way was found - microservices. It does not cover all libs, but those, which are used in Spring Boot it will.